# Error Icon in the Unity-panel

Tags: unity, icons, panel

I tried to install Teamviewer on Ubuntu and ran into an error. After this error, I cannot get rid of this "Error Icon" from the Unity-panel. Does anyone know how to remove this? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get install -f` to fix the broken packages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: Ok, I just ran that sudo apt and it properly installed Teamviewer, and the icon disappeared. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, when an application does not fully install, you need to fix the broken dependency chain. To resolve your issues, run:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and Apt will attempt to fix all recent installation issues.